# HTML, PHP - Redirecting example.com/blogs to example.com/blogs.php

Tags: php, html

How do I redirect `example.com/blogs` to `example.com/blogs.php`?

Comment: as of this writing, all the answers given would serve the content (from both urls) not necessarily redirect.   I wonder if that's what John is asking for and doesn't realize it, or if he actually wants the content to redirect.

Comment: I think serving the content form either URL is all I want.

Comment: If you have the same content accessible on two different URLs you might want to use the new canonical link in your HTML head to prevent duplicate content issues. See this post by  Matt Cutts for more info: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/

Answer (score 5):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogs /blogs.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried this and it's not working.  It gives me a 404 if I type in example.com/blogs.

I wonder if I changed the .htaccess file correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, the easiest thing to do is to enable the [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option in your `httpd.conf` file (to enable it globally) or in a `.htaccess` file (to enable it per-directory).

> The effect of `MultiViews` is as follows: if the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo`, if `/some/dir` has `MultiViews` enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Translation into English: it will see `blogs` doesn't exist, but `blogs.php` does, so it will load `blogs.php`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to rewrite the URL.  This is not for the faint of heart but if you want to do it then you should check out a [tutorial on URL rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/).

Answer (score 0):

You could be a total cheater and make a directory "/blogs" and inside blogs have a file index.php, and in index.php write:

```
header("Location: ../blogs.php");
```

Which just redirects to the correct page... 
This is just an alternate suggestion to the much better suggestions above... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>redirect</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com/blogs.php">
    </head>
</html>
```